# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null at mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool

Tags: java

There are many Errors like these  :  Maybe

1. jvm init config of  stack—— -xxsm should be higher ?
2. the com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:616)  code is wrong ?

.

```
2015-09-06 12:55:52.537 [tourPromotionCalcListenerTaskExecutor-8] WARN  c.t.j.d.c.DynamicConsumeMessageListenerContainer -Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.Object.toString(Object.java:219) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2826) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115) ~[na:1.6.0_30]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:616) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:633) ~[c3p0-0.9.5-pre8.jar:0.9.5-pre8]
```

could some expert  help me ?? TKS

Comment: Have you tried using a version of c3p0 which isn't a pre-release? I suggest you try 0.9.5.1...

Comment: Looks like an infinite recursion.

Comment: @JonSkeet   i have seen  0.9.5.1's code . it s the same!

Comment: @Henry it's right .  the sourcecode  of cp30:http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool.java.html

Answer (score 0):

Check at your method its looping itself without a break

```
 public void prelimCheckoutResource() {
      ....
      ....
      prelimCheckoutResource()
 }
```

or

```
public void methodA()
{
  methodB();
}

public void methodB()
{
 methodA();
}
```

See also: [What is a StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror)

Comment: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool.java.html